# Missing "New Submission" button in DSpace

Tags: dspace

I have installed DSpace 6 on my Debian/Linux 10 machine via Docker following that instructions: https://github.com/DSpace/DSpace/tree/dspace-6_x/dspace/src/main/docker-compose.

All works fine including the xml-UI, but there is **no "New Submission" or "Upload" button available** at all. Even if I am logged is as admin user and navigating to an collection or community on the UI. So I don't see any opportitunity to ingesting content and metadata to my repository.

Does anyone know how to upload/submit any new documents to the repo or how to make the responsible button visible?

[Screenshot of the UI where an upload button should be visible following the DSpace manual](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JKzxR.jpg)

Comment: Assuming that you are able to create collections and communities, as an admin in the UI, the only thing I could think of are caching related issues: clear cache & reload the page of the collection.

Comment: Yes I am able to create collections and communities, but even clearing cach and reloading didnt solve my problem. Thanks anyway!

Comment: I don't understand German based from your screenshot, but "ein dokument in dieser sammlung veröffentlichen" when Google translate means "publish a document in this collection". What happens when you click that link?